# Unable to get import_role working with tasks_from

Tags: import, ansible, roles

I am trying to use import_role in playbook with tasks_from. But when I parameterize and pass as extra vars, the parameter is not replaced with actual value

It works with include_role

kafka.yml

```
- hosts: myhost1
  remote_user: kafkauser
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - import_role:
         name: mykafka
         tasks_from: "{{ action }}.yml"
```

**Actual result:**

```
ansible-playbook ./kafka.yml -i hosts/DEV/DEVHOSTS--extra-var 'action=install'
ERROR! Could not find specified file in role: tasks/{{ action }}.yml
```

**Expected Result:**

```
tasks/install.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

try "action=install" with double quotes and debug properly with --verbose.

ansible-playbook -i hosts/DEV/DEVHOSTS kafka.yml --extra-vars "action=install" --verbose

Comment: `ansible-playbook ./kafka.yml -i hosts/DEV/hosts --extra-vars "action=install" --verbose
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
ERROR! Could not find specified file in role: tasks/{{ action }}.yml`

Comment: Have you tried with absolute path of your role in plybook. Write the  path from root.